# SQL select values that contain numbers only

Tags: mysql, sql

Im looking to select only valid number values from table (ean, gtin, upc or barcode)

What is the difference between the 2 statements, as they give me different results.

```
select count(*) from catalogue where barcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';

select count(*) from catalogue where barcode NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%';
```

Regards

Comment: `not like` doesn't understand `[0-9]` as a range...

Comment: ...but RLIKE does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic in MySQL:

```
where barcode NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

chooses any `barcode` that is does not consist only of digits.

This logic in MySQL:

```
where barcode NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%';
```

chooses any `barcode` that does not have the four characters `'['`,, `'0'`, `'-'`, and `']'` adjacent to each other in that order in the string.

In other words, `LIKE` does not recognize character classes in MySQL.

You can also write the logic to identify non-numbers as:

```
where barcode REGEXP '[^0-9]'
```

That is, it contains a character that is not a digit.